# Why does my Spark application fail to run with "NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.util.SystemClock"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to connect to Kafka from apache Spark streaming using Java API not scala.

I am getting following error:

> **Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.apache.spark.util.SystemClock.()**  at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)

Error is popping up when  creating JavaStreamingContext object.

This is my code:

```
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext("local[2]", "KafkaWordCount",
            new Duration(2000), System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),
            JavaStreamingContext.jarOfClass(JavaKafkaWordCount.class));

    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    topicMap.put("fast-messages", 2);

    JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, "localhost:9092", "test", topicMap);

    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
     // @Override
      public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
        return tuple2._2();
      }
    });
```

Jar versions:

> spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 - 1.6.2 
>   spark-core_2.11            - 1.2.1
>   spark-streaming_2.10       - 1.6.0

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `spark-core_2.10`

That's because of dependency mismatch regarding their Scala version in use.

See `spark-streaming-kafka_2.10` and `spark-core_2.11` and `spark-streaming_2.10`. The streaming jars are compiled for Scala 2.10 while spark-core is for 2.11.

It does not force you to use Scala over Java. Spark is written using Scala mostly and dependencies built using Scala have to match their Scala version.